# Select next higher number in array based on a minimum criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
              A           B              C       D 
1             0         0.99          Minimum:   6
2             1         0.99          Input:     3
3             2         2.99          Result:    4.99
4             3         2.99
5             4         4.99
6             5         4.99
7             6         7.99         
8             7         7.99
9             8         9.99 
10            9         9.99
```

The formula in cell **D3** is:

```
=LARGE(B$1:B$10,COUNTIF(B$1:B$10,">"&D2))
```

This formula selects the next highest number in the array in
**Column B** based on the input in cell **D3**.
For example:
If the input in cell **D3** is *3* it will select
4.99 instead of 2.99.
All this works perfectly with the formula in cell **D3**.

However, now I want to insert a minimum criteria into this system
in cell **D1**.
For example: If the minimum is 6 the formula in cell **D3** should notice it
and select 7.99 instead of 4.99.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?
Is there a way to do it without using an array formula?

Comment: you prefer with VBA ? or a formula ?

Comment: Formula would be better.

Comment: OK, try my formula below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS` to include multiple criteria, instead of your `COUNTIF`.

So in Cell D3 put the formula below:

```
=LARGE(B$1:B$10,COUNTIFS(B$1:B$10,">"&D2,B$1:B$10,">"&D1))
```

It means that the formula is searching for 2 criterias:

1. Cells Value is larger than value in Cell D2 (`Input`).
2. Cells Value is larger than value in Cell D1 (`Minimum`).

Comment: Yep, I feel there's a better way to my answer - I really should try waking up before posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using INDEX/MATCH you could restrict the range that's looked at, although I feel there's a better way:

`=LARGE(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($D$1,$A:$A,0)):INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($A:$A)),COUNTIF(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($D$1,$A:$A,0)):INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($A:$A)),">"&$D$2))`

You could place the INDEX/MATCH into a named range to make the formula shorter.